# How to search for multiple files with different names using Get-Childitem?

Tags: windows, powershell, file

I'm trying to find a lot of different files that are stored across multiple drives with randomly generated names, they all have the same file extension. I can get the names from the program that creates them but I want to automate the search and copy function to move them to a separate folder here is what I have so far but it fails to compile:

```
$paths="C:\","D:\","E:\","F:\"
$files="FileA", “FileB”,”FileC”

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Length; $i++) {
$file="*" + $files[i] + "*.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Path $paths -recurse -Filter $file | Out-File C:\report.txt
} 

Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

If I want to run the command manually like so it outputs the file path to the report.txt file fine:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $paths -recurse -Filter *FileA*.icl | Out-File C:\report.txt
```

Additionally how can I then take the list this generates and copy all of them to a seperate folder?

Comment: That's very inefficient. With a loop like this you will search all drives multiple times. Instead of `-Filter` you may use `-Include` because you can provide an array of names.

Comment: adding to Olaf's comment, by "failed to compile" I assume you mean there is an error, if so, `$files[i]` should be `$files[$i]`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon correcting $files[i] to $files[$i] did clear the error I was receiving Thank you sir I appreciate your input!

Comment: @Olaf Would you mind expanding on the use of -Include? Should I remove the double * and just search the array?

Comment: New problem after correcting the error the for loop is overwriting the report.txt file each time. Is there a better way for me to save the output?

Comment: Use the `-Append` parameter. `| Out-File C:\report.txt -Append`

Answer (score 2):

What [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) pointed out in his helpful comment is that you can leverage the `-Include` parameter which can take an array of wildcard patterns, whereas `-Filter` takes a single string. This would improve your code because there would be **a single call to `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` instead of one call per item in `$files`.**

Regarding the "failure to compile", which presumably is a syntax error in `$files[i]` when it should be `$files[$i]`.

Regarding copying the found files to a destination folder, see the added `Copy-Item` line, taking the found files, copying them to a destination folder (**change the path to an existing one**), then the details of those copied files are stored in a `report.csv` file, note the use of `Export-Csv` instead of `Out-File`, you're dealing with objects here not with plain text thus **you want to use a cmdlet designed to convert objects into structured data**.

```
$paths = 'C:\', 'D:\', 'E:\', 'F:\'
$files = 'FileA', 'FileB', 'FileC'

$patterns = $files.ForEach({ [WildcardPattern]::Escape($_) + '*.txt' })
Get-ChildItem -Path $paths -Recurse -Include $patterns |
    Copy-Item -Destination path\to\theDestinationFolder -PassThru |
    Export-Csv C:\report.csv -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host 'Press any key to continue...'
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')
```